# Module aliases in bazel

Tags: java, maven, bazel

Bazel uses location based referencing scheme. However, if you want to move your modules around, this creates a problem with refactorings. Is it possible to emulate a logical naming scheme, similar to one in maven i.e. package.module.submodule?

Comment: I think it would be a great idea if you choose to make the code base you move around a lot into a workspace instead of a module, so that you can refer to this workspace in your `WORKSPACE` file as a external dependency using the `local_repository` rule, and you can refer to it in your `BUILD` file as `@workspace_name//package:target`. This way, if you choose to move the workspace into other places, you only have to make one edit, which is to change its location in the `WORKSPACE` file.

Comment: Or, maybe, you create a target that proxies the targets defined in the module(s) that you move a lot using `LANG_library` rule (include those targets in the `deps` attribute), that way, you only need to change the location of the module, you only have to make changes to this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a mechanism exactly like this in bazel, but I have two suggestions:

1. Move the package, and rename every reference to the old package to the new package. You can use `bazel query` to find the dependencies on a package. If you have only a few references to the old package, that's pretty easy, but if you have many references then that's harder. You can use a tool like [buildozer](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/tree/master/buildozer) to do the renaming automatically.
2. Move the package, and create a BUILD file where the old package was with [`alias()` rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#alias) to each target in the new package. This might be annoying to maintain though.